# Tikzmath, ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

I'm trying to use tikzmath to draw lines between a set of points, however I've an error `ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.` on the line `\ni=\i+1;`. Any idea why?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    \n=5;
  }
  \foreach \i in {-\n,...,\n} {
    \foreach \j in {-\n,...,\n} {
      \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] at ($(\i+.3*\j,.5*\j)$) (n-\i-\j) {};
    }
  }
  \foreach \i in {-\n,...,\n-1} {
    \foreach \j in {-\n,...,\n-1} {
      \tikzmath{%
        \ni=\i+1;
        \nj=\j+1;
      };
      \draw[] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\nj);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `\ni` is defined to be a number in TeX’s eyes (it’s defined with `\mathchardef`). If I change `\ni` to `\nx`, I don't get the error, but other ones due to wrong code.

Comment: Addition to @egreg's comment the wrong code is the last `\n-1` parts in the foreach list. TikZ doesn't evaluate the expressions there. You might add `\numexpr` before it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to how `\tikzmath` works, you *can’t* use variable names that correspond to already defined commands that point to mathematical symbols.

The standard definition of `\ni` is by `\mathchardef\ni="3233` (in a glorified form in `fontmath.ltx`) and TeX considers `\mathchardef` tokens as numbers when it’s looking for them.

The same error happens, for instance, if I use `\propto` instead of `\ni`.

Use another name.

With other fixes, as suggested by percusse:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    \n=5;
  }
  \foreach \i in {-\n,...,\n} {
    \foreach \j in {-\n,...,\n} {
      \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] at ($(\i+.3*\j,.5*\j)$) (\n-\i-\j) {};
    }
  }
  \foreach \i in {-\n,...,\numexpr\n-1} {
    \foreach \j in {-\n,...,\numexpr\n-1} {
      \tikzmath{%
        \nni=\i+1;
        \nj=\j+1;
      };
      \draw[] (\n-\i-\j) -- (\n-\i-\nj);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also do `\let\ni\undefined` at the start of the `tikzpicture`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{5}
  \foreach \i in {-\n,...,\n} {
    \foreach \j in {-\n,...,\n} {
      \node[circle,inner sep=1pt] at ($(\i+.3*\j,.5*\j)$) (n-\i-\j) {};
    }
  }
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using int(\i+1)] in {-\n,...,\numexpr\n-1} {
    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \nj using int(\j+1)] in {-\n,...,\numexpr\n-1} {
      \draw (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ni-\nj);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```